# Laravel 4 - Route to the controller with an optional parameter

Tags: php, routes, laravel-4

How can I make a routing with an optional parameter which will not raise an error if there is no parameter provided ?

My `app/routes.php` looks like this:

```
Route::get('/{slug}', 'PageController@page');
```

And the `app/controllers/PageController.php`:

```
class PageController extends BaseController {

    public $layout = 'templates.default.tpl';

    public function page( $slug = 'front' )
    {
        return View::make('pages.'.$slug);
    }

}
```

So if you go to `www.websiteurl.com/` , without any parameter, you should arrive to the default `front` page. Instead I'am getting an error

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException
```

How can I tell to Laravel4, to make routing 2nd  variable optional ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define your route like:

```
Route::get('/{slug?}', 'PageController@page');
```

Questionmark tells laravel that this parameter is optional. More on [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-parameters)

Comment: Oh, I was looking for it in another section. Thank you